# glassfish asadmin error

Tags: command-line, glassfish

I am trying to start the GlassFish Server from the command line:

I typed in the following command:

> asadmin start-domain -verbose

or

> asadmin start-domain domain1

or

> asadmin start-domain

I'm looking over the error output.  I see this first:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Sun\
>   SDK\domains\domain\config\domain-registry (Access is denied)

Thanks.
Sally

Comment: Anything else after this error? And in the server logs? What OS are you running?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19879-01/821-0177/abgdu/index.html This link will help you.

Answer (score 1):

basically try running GF in superuser mode or change permission of the files in domain directory appropriately

In windows:

1. open command prompt as administrator
2. run command

> asadmin start-domain doman1

In linux: 
  execute command with root permission. i.e

> sudo asadmin start-domain doman1

Answer (score 0):

Try running as administrator

asadmin start-domain doman1

Comment: A bit of explanation, what this command means would be very helpful.